# Cannot find module '@jest/globals' from 'abc.test.js'

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-jest

Has anyone encountered this kind of an error? We had a bunch of jest js files that were working a few months but now are failing. Can any JEST experts help?

Comment: This is probably due to the fact that you upgrade the `@lwc/jest-preset` to the latest version without upgrading to Jest 25.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was an unfortunate mismatch between dependencies of dependencies when using the base LWC Jest testing packages. More specifically, if you happen to get a `babel-preset-jest` version < 25.5.4 but are running `jest` version >= 25.5.4. The exact version of these dependencies probably depends on when you installed or upgraded your dependencies and what your `package-lock.json` or `yarn.lock` look like.

The fix is to upgrade all Jest related dependencies to be >= 25.5.4, or pin them all below. If you're using `@salesforce/sfdx-lwc-jest` to run your tests, this was fixed already in the `prerelease` branch.

This was fixed in the sfdx-lwc-jest project here: https://github.com/salesforce/sfdx-lwc-jest/pull/152